# Laravel Undefined property: stdClass::$id error

Tags: php, forms, laravel-5

I am very much new to laravel, and even some minor errors scares me..i am fetching the data from a table with name 'student' but while i do that i am getting an error as

> Undefined property: stdClass::$id

it would be great if i get some help here..thank you

**StudViewController.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class StudViewController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function index(){
      $users = DB::select('select * from student');
      return view('stud_view',['users'=>$users]);
   }
}
```

**stud_view.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
<table border = 1>
         <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Name</td>
         </tr>
         @foreach ($users as $user)
         <tr>
            <td>{{ $user->id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
         </tr>
         @endforeach
      </table>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('view-records','StudViewController@index');
```

Comment: `print_r($users)` and check `id` key exist or not.

Comment: I got an output as Array..!

Comment: Show me your array.

Comment: Sorry it is `Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [Id] => 1 [Name] => hari prasad ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [Id] => 2 [Name] => prajwal ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [Id] => 3 [Name] => sunil ) )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
 <tr>
    <td>{{ $user->Id }}</td>
    <td>{{ $user->Name }}</td>
 </tr>
 @endforeach
```